# How to use Wink API V2 from a non-web app

Tags: php, api, wink

I have a command-line PHP application running on a 5min cron retrieving data from an internal web-service and calling a nimbus(former cloud-clock) device via the Wink API. - This was running great for the last few years.
When authenticating with password grant and my V1 API Keys authentication fails with the message

`This client is not permitted to use the password grant type`

It seems that Wink has abandoned the old authentication and asks users to register for new API keys at https://developer.wink.com - The process asks for a redirect URL which makes only sense for web-apps.

**Finally my question**: How can I authenticate with the new Wink API from a command-line script if I do not have a redirect URI?

Comment: Does really no one use this API? The documentation is very limited in details.  Or like, its detailed, but not 100% useful in order to implement.  I'll figure it out and get back (I hope!)  A bit late for OP but I'm sure others will find it helpful.  I'm trying to use PHP...

Comment: Share your code, stripped down.  I got this to work with a user interface (login).  I'm hoping I can merge mine with yours to get it to work.

Comment: Similiar, but uses a UI login: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53127069/wink-api-v2-hello-world-in-php/53127890#53127890